# In bash, why is `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe"` gramatically correct?

Tags: bash

On Ubuntu-like linux, the default `.bashrc` file contains a line:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
```

Then why is `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe` grammatically correct? What page of `man bash` can I know the meaning of this statement? To me, this statement seems the same as, for example,

```
ls echo
```

, which is invalid. Also,

```
abc=hello echo $abc
```

makes no error but outputs null.

I couldn't find any relevant information in `man bash` though I tried some `/<expression>` search command on `less`. Could anyone please tell me the interpretations of the command?

---

Note: I've read the post "[Can you explain eval expression in the default .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724351/can-you-explain-eval-expression-in-the-default-bashrc)" but got nothing.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. Actually my post seems duplicate. But how did you find the post you cited? Before I post this entry, I surfed the internet, but couldn't find that. I would like to know not to repeat the same mistake.

Comment: it's no biggie, I guess my search-fu is just stronger ;) The relevant section of the bash man page is probably `SHELL GRAMMAR` - `Simple Commands` where it says *A simple command is a sequence of optional  variable  assignments  followed  by  blank-separated  words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator.* but unless you're a syntax weenie that's rather hard to recognize IMHO

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. I should have first read through the chapter of `SHELL GRAMMAR` in `man bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As steeldriver said, `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe` is a *simple command*, which is defined as a sequence of:

- optional variable assignments (here `SHELL=/bin/sh`), followed by...
- **blank**-separated words and redirections (here `lesspipe`), terminated by...
- a *control operator*, which includes a newline character.

Your first example:

```
ls echo
```

is actually a valid command: only the first word is treated as a command to execute, the rest are given to that command as parameters¹.

In the case of a `ls` command, if there is a sub-directory named `echo` in the current directory, its contents will be listed; if there is a non-directory named `echo`, its name will be displayed². If neither is true, the command will return an error and display a `No such file or directory` error message.

Your second example:

```
abc=hello echo $abc
```

is again a simple command with a variable assignment, but it also includes a variable expansion (`$abc`). The **EXPANSION** chapter of `man bash` defines the various kinds of expansion and their order of operations.

After the command line has been split into words, the shell checks for expansions:

- brace expansion: nothing applicable
- tilde expansion: nothing applicable
- parameter and variable expansion: here `$abc` is replaced by the current value of shell or environment variable named `abc`. But since this command line has not been executed yet, the variable assignment earlier on the line (`abc=hello`) is not in effect yet. As a result, `$abc` is replaced by whatever value `abc` had before, or an empty string if it was not set. The empty string is then removed completely since it was not quoted.
- command substitution: nothing applicable
- arithmetic expansion: nothing applicable
- word splitting: the only candidate for this would have been the result of the `$abc` variable expansion, but there is nothing to split in a null string.
- pathname expansion: nothing applicable

Once the expansions are done, the variable `abc` in the environment of the to-be-started utility is set to value "hello" and the command `echo` is executed. It outputs just a single blank line.

---

<sup>¹ strictly speaking, `ls` is also passed as argument, as its `argv[0]`. `ls` uses that argument to know how it was invoked, uses it as well in the error messages it outputs, but doesn't consider it as an option or file to act upon.</sup>

<sup>² if it is a symbolic link, but its target can't be resolved, some `ls` implementations will however output an error message as if the file didn't exist</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Is the command executed in sub-shell? Some answers of the post of which my post was judged as duplicate say the "simple command" is the same as `(export var=value command)`. However, the chapters of `Simple Commands` and `SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION` don't refer to it.

Comment: @ynn The `COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT` chapter told me it's true: ***When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is  invoked in a separate execution environment***